# Finding the correct x and y widths of 2D array for Gaussian fit

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, gaussian, data-fitting

I'd like to fit my 2D numpy array (image) data to a Gaussian. I've read a lot of examples using `scipy.optimize`, and I've tried but the fit has never been good -- this is probably because my background is non-zero, and sometimes I have other peaks too. I think it might be easier for me to simply generate a Gaussian that has the parameters of the correct peak. I already have the subpixel centroid coordinates `x` and `y` of the peak I want, and can easily get the amplitude of the peak with `data[y][x]`, although I guess I would have to round the coordinates. What I'm stuck on now is the x and y widths. My Gaussian function looks like this:

```
import numpy as np

def gaussian_func(xy, x0, y0, width_x, width_y, amp): #x0 and y0 are the centroid coordinates
    x = xy[0]
    y = xy[1]
    offset = np.min(data) #should this be a median value of the background instead?
    a = 1/(2*width_x**2)
    c = 1/(2*width_y**2)
    exp_term = a*(x-x0)**2 + c*(y-y0)**2
    return (offset + amp * np.exp(-exp_term)).ravel()

x, y = np.arange(0, np.shape(data)[1], 1), np.arange(0, np.shape(data)[0], 1)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)

gaussian = gaussian_func((xx, yy), x0, y0, width_x, width_y, amp)
gaussian = np.reshape(gaussian, np.shape(data))
```

So I'm basically just confused on what to insert for `width_x` and `width_y`. I know these terms are supposed to be interchangeable with the standard deviations in x and y, but when I tried simply using `np.std(data)`, I got bad results. Do the widths correspond to the actual physical widths of the peak? If so, how do I find those? Thanks!

Comment: Check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_width_at_half_maximum) to see how the FWHM is connected to the standard deviation.

Comment: Thank you. It does seem simpler to just use the relation `width = 2.355 * sigma` (described in that link) in my code. But I am confused on how to compute the correct `sigma` along each axis x and y. I have various points in my 2D array (x, y) that give me values z(x, y). Normally `np.std` along axes 0 or 1 would work for a set of points x that give a value y, for example. So I'm not sure how to implement that here?

Comment: ...even worse, if your Gaussian has unequal `sig_x` and `sig_y` and is rotated, you woun't get this by a 1D slice. How strong are the other peaks in your image. Maybe there is a way to stick to the original plan and make a proper 2D fit? Or did you try to fit a 1D Gaussian to the 1D slice of your data (assuming that it is not rotated)?

Comment: It's not rotated, but it presumably has different `sig_x` and `sig_y`. Is there a straightforward way to just calculate these sigmas in my code? I'm doing this with multiple images, so some images don't have strong other peaks, but others do. How would fitting a 1D Gaussian work? Do you mean doing this for x and y?

Comment: You could calculate the sigma at any 1D slice that does not have additional peaks. If automated, you can use chi**2 as indicator, start near the maximum and move outwards. If you can interpret the additional peaks/spikes as outliers, I may refer (once again) to [robust least square fitting](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/robust_regression.html)

Comment: Can you provide code that generates some reasonable artificial data?